# mouseleave() not deleting class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have a problem with my jQuery code. When I mouseenter on blue button (`icon_disabled`) I want to add to it class `icons-visible` which shows its white background and I want to display `disabled_list` (red `p` on picture). When I leave red `disabled_list` I want to `display: none` it again and remove the class which I previously added. Console logs works fine, but I can't delete class and `display: none` the red `p`. Why? :(

```
var icon_disabled = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(2)");
var disabled_list = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(5)");

        $(icon_disabled).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
            $(disabled_list).css("display","block");
        });

        $(disabled_list).mouseleave(function() {
            $(icon_disabled).removeClass("icons-visible");
            $(this).css("display","none");
            console.log("testing");
        });
```

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="block-plywajaceikony">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p> //here I add and trying to remove class "icons-visible"
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p> //here is my red p with icons
</div>
```

Comment: show also your html please

Comment: Are you sure your selectors (```#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(5)```) are right?

Comment: it works as charm :https://jsfiddle.net/wno21v3q/

Comment: Your code works fine. It adds the class and removes it property when leaving the last child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/6zbnseL3/4/

```
var icon_disabled = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(2)");
var disabled_list = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(5)");

$(icon_disabled).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
        $(disabled_list).css("display","block");
    });

$(disabled_list).mouseleave(function() {
        $(icon_disabled).removeClass("icons-visible");
        $(this).css("display","none");
        console.log("testing");
    });
```

However, I think you should go with another interaction concept. Hovering on one element and removing it by hovering over another is super unintuitive. Better use an interactive element known to the user. For example a toggle: Click on button -> button changes color (pressed state) -> content appears -> click button again to deactivate. (Can be done using a checkbox).

Answer (score 1):

```
var icon_disabled = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(2)");
var disabled_list = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(5)");
    $(icon_disabled).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
        $(disabled_list).css("display","block");
    });

    $(disabled_list).on('mouseleave',function() {
        $(icon_disabled).removeClass("icons-visible");
        $(this).css("display","none");
        console.log("testing");
    });
```

```js
var icon_disabled = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(2)");
var disabled_list = document.querySelector("#block-plywajaceikony p:nth-child(5)");

        $(icon_disabled).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).addClass("icons-visible");
            $(disabled_list).css("display","block");
        });

        $(disabled_list).on("mouseleave",function() {
            $(icon_disabled).removeClass("icons-visible");
            $(this).css("display","none");
            console.log("testing");
        });
```

```css
body{
  color:white;
  
}

.collapsed{
  display: none;
}

#easy-id{
  background-color: black;
  padding:20px;
}


p{
   background-color:red;
}

p:nth-child(2){
  background-color:blue;
}

p:nth-child(5){
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-plywajaceikony">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>Enter to Show</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>Leave to Hide</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question - there appears to be unformated code at the top.  Please also add a description explaining what changes you've made and how this fixes the problem.